# LiveConnectClient missing eventhandlers Live SDK 5.3 WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

hi there :) il get right to it.

Problem : 
when i try to instanciate LiveConnectClient and then try to access the event : GetCompleted
which supose to be in the LiveConnectClient is not showing and on all the examples i been looking at even those on here are using it. this is not the only class this is happening on it is also happening on LiveAuthClient as well no events even the post on the net says there should be.

i tried to reinstall Vs2012 and sdk wp8 and live sdk from scratch but have not solved it

for refrence i using this example to see if i can it to work :

```
    //event triggered when Skydrive sign in status is changed
    private void btnSignIn_SessionChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Live.Controls.LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if the user is signed in
        if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            session = e.Session;

            client = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);
            infoTextBlock.Text = "Accessing SkyDrive...";

            //get the folders in their skydrive

            client.GetCompleted +=
                new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(btnSignin_GetCompleted);

            client.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files?filter=folders,albums");
        }

        //otherwise the user isn't signed in
        else
        {
            infoTextBlock.Text = "Not signed in.";
            client = null;
        }

    }
```

i got no luck solving it and running out of ideas. So im hoping one of u boys out there can shed some light on it or lend a hand with dew wise words :)

thanks in advance. and i do apologies if this is to long a post.

regards jens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it seems like those events have been removed in the latest versions of the SDK. You don't need them though, thanks to the async/await keywords. First, mark your method as `async`, then call the `GetAsync` method with the `await` keyword. And place afterward the code you would normally put in the `GetCompleted` event:

```
private async void btnSignIn_SessionChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Live.Controls.LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //if the user is signed in
    if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
    {
        session = e.Session;

        client = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);
        infoTextBlock.Text = "Accessing SkyDrive...";

        //get the folders in their skydrive
        var result = await client.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files?filter=folders,albums");

        // Do here what you would normally do in btnSignin_GetCompleted
    }

    //otherwise the user isn't signed in
    else
    {
        infoTextBlock.Text = "Not signed in.";
        client = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks kookiz that explain a few things tho some what easier way tho il admit just wish there were bit more examples out there of it guess it is stil bit new again thanks alot :)