# Cannot await 'void' error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-7.1

I'm developing a WP7.1 app on VS2012.

I'd like to use Live SDK for uploading a file to Skydrive. However, when I'm implementing the event handler method which is given as a sample on msdn.com I got the error "Cannot await 'void' " here:

```
private async void btnSignin_SessionChanged(object sender, LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            client = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);
            LiveOperationResult operationResult = await client.GetAsync("me");
```

I already installed this (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx?PageIndex=2) library, but it only resolved the problem with the "async" keyword.

Comment: You can only `await` objects which have a `GetAwaiter` method. `void` is not an object, and thus does not have methods.

Comment: Just so we're clear here, that error is occurring on the [`GetAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh534049.aspx) call right?  It doesn't return `void` so I don't see why it would cause that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LiveConnectClient` is probably using the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern, which is not directly convertible to an `await`able method. You can wrap EAP into a `Task` by using `TaskCompletionSource` as [described on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#EAP).

Comment: Ah, [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321190/liveconnectclient-missing-eventhandlers-live-sdk-5-3-wp8) seems to suggest that an older version of the SDK was event-based. I guess he should probably just get the latest version if possible.

Comment: @JeffMercado: I believe that the (current) SDK uses an event-based API *when on Windows Phone 7* (whereas the same SDK on Win8 / WP8 uses TAP). So I suspect the actual `GetAsync` the op is calling is [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh534050) which results in [this event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/microsoft.live.liveconnectclient.getcompleted).